# Restarting ColdFusion mail queue

Tags: coldfusion, administration

We are currently experiencing intermittent mail queue stoppages.  I'm [seeking diagnostic help in another area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94932/coldfusion-mail-queue-stops-processing).

In the meantime, is there a way to restart the CF mail queue without restarting the service as a whole?

CF8 standard
Win2k3

Solution:  We are now checking the age of the oldest file in the mail queue.  When it exceeds a set age (currently 30 min) the mail queue is restarted.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes there is.

```
<cfset sFactory = CreateObject("java","coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory")>
<cfset MailSpoolService = sFactory.mailSpoolService>
<cfset MailSpoolService.stop()>
<cfset MailSpoolService.start()>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does this work in both cases: Using the CF Mail queue, as well as mail spooling?

Comment: This is very useful.  I just wrote a script today that checks the spool because our cfmail queues are hanging intermittently as well.

Comment: Unless Adobe's policy has changed, using the ServiceFactory is unsupported and may break on future versions.

Comment: Nice... that one is getting saved for future hacking... further proving the mantra "When CF fails, just have Java to do it directly."